# How to Apologize for a Late Reply

Tags: email

I am working as a support representative and want to send the mail to which i missed the ticket. Issue is ticket is submitted by the end user and customers IT team resolved it within the ( SLA ) time but same ticket created on our portal also i missed to send the reply and there IT team resolved the issue. Now i want to send them mail how to frame it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not an email writing service.

Comment: To whom do you wish to write a email?  The end user?  IT?  Are there complaints being made that the ticket was not followed up on?  Additional information would be helpful.

Comment: the mail goes to end user, there IT team and my lead and team members also...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Hi **xxx**
>
> Please accept my apologies for the delayed response, it seems we had a minor technical issue at our end.
>
> The issue was resolved on **date**, although we may not have communicated this with you.
>
> If you have any further issues, please let me know